# Can tld files be accessed from WEB-INF\lib\{*.jar}\META-INF\resources\WEB-INF directory?

Tags: java, jboss, taglib, servlet-3.0

I have a jsp file which include a tag like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="abc" uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/xyz.tld" %>
```

and in my app, the deploy structure is:

```
WEB-INF
  |-lib
      |-some.jar
          |-META-INF
              |-resources
                  |-WEB-INF
                      |-tlds
                          |-xyz.tld
```

this works fine in Tomcat 7, but when I deploy my app to JBoss as 7, it can not find the tld file.

so, is it an issue of JBoss(not support Servlet3.0?) or the tld files just can not accessed from META-INF\resources\WEB-INF directory in a jar?

Comment: Can you please post the error stack here ?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a Servlet 3.0 issue, it's a JSP 2.2 question. (They're different specifications).

The `uri` portion of the taglib declaration is not a location. It is a key and must correspond to the content of the

```
<uri>your/tld/uri</uri>
```

element in the tld file.

If this element is missing then you must declare it in a taglib map in the web.xml, providing the uri there:

```
<jsp-config>
     <taglib>
         <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tlds/xyz.tld</taglib-uri>
         <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/some.jar/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/tlds/xyz.tld</taglib-location>
     </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: Alternate solution that works too:  in the TLD file declare element <uri>your/tld/uri</url>  rather than in the map in web.xml